# Trying to get the year over year percentage increase for each zone and each school row in Tableau Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, calculation

I tired the calculation needed for the total yoy but I have to show the yoy percentage change per year according to the zone and the school.

I tired the calculation needed for the total yoy but I have to show the yoy percentage change per year according to the zone and the school. I have included the sample excel sheet which has the result needed display. Can someone suggest how to show the percentage changes per row. The files hold more data for understanding. I have created a rollup to show dynamic results of zone/school based on what is selected.

Thank you,
Result needed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an69G.png)

Dashboard
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrb0m.png)